# Read News from Wordpress Site into iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, wordpress, parsing

i want do develop an app for someone, to read the news from his Wordpress website. 
I have tried several things like the MWFeedParser (but there I can't display images) 
and I found a link often: http://www.kieranmcgrady.com/blog/2012/4/25/tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-rss-reader-for-ios.html but this website is expired.

The MWFeedParser is very good but I don't know how the parse images with it...

Is there another framework or something like that to easy parse a wordpress site with images ?

This is what i want to parse:

```
<img src="the_url" alt="the description" width="460" height="352" class="size-full wp-image-16009 colorbox-16008" />
```

Comment: I think his code (no tutorial) is at https://github.com/KieranMcGrady/RSSReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to download the image yourself. Have a look at https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage for a great framework implementing lazy download of images. You only need to provide the URL to `SDImageView` and it will start downloading the image while displaying a placeholder image.

You can use `NSRegularExpression` to extract the `img` information from your feed:

```
NSString *context = ...;
NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<img[^>]*src=['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"][^>]*>"
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:context
                               options: NSMatchingReportCompletion
                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [context length])];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches objectAtIndex:0];
NSRange range = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
NSString *result = [context substringWithRange:range];
```

Note that in the snippet above I am doing a couple of assumption on the format of the `img` tag. If it does not work, it would help if you could post the exact string you get.

Comment: But I don't know how to parse out the image URL for each news item ?

Comment: as far as I know, RSS has not provision for images attached to RSS items. (I might be wrong on this). So, the question is: in what format does the image url information come to you? Is it embedded in some regular field or is it in a custom field?

Comment: it's in the <img tag and in that there is somewhere in the middle a src="url" .

Comment: and the <img tag is in the middle of the content text

Comment: @user1163463 - if you can add a sample of the feed in your question, that would be very helpful.

Comment: *context ist the xml file is it ?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote 'context', but I meant 'content'... have you tried my code?

Comment: I am pretty new to Objective C and don't where I will get the content from MWFeedParser.

Comment: I found the conttnt (item.content) but when I set your code i get this error.  { 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSRegularExpression enumerateMatchesInString:options:range:usingBlock:]: nil argument'}

Comment: double check that you are not passing a `nil` first argument (the one I called `context`). is `item.content` not `nil`?

Comment: no, it's not nil... when I NSLog item.content I get the exact text that I wanted.

Comment: please check my edit. there were some issues with the code I posted. I hope this will fix it for you. notice that I am not doing any kind of error checking.

Comment: doesn't work either... I set NSString *content = item.content; right ?

Comment: yes, context/content = item.content... really I have no idea why it does not work. I tried with the string you posted and it works for me...

Comment: I have updated my question with the exact text (don't wonder, it's german :D). Maybe I've said something wrong above with the <img tag...

Comment: don't know why but it works now, just put it into a view controller instead in the Parser itself. Much thanks!!!

Comment: Hey, it's me again with a question on your Code above.
1) Sometimes there are no pictures in the post from my website. Can you show me how to build a If-Clause to check that ?